# Why does "\u1FFF:foo".StartsWith(":") return true?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, clr

The string `"\u1FFF:foo"` starts with `\u1FFF` (or "῿"), right?

So how can these both be true?

```
"\u1FFF:foo".StartsWith(":")       // equals true
"\u1FFF:foo".StartsWith("\u1FFF")  // equals true

// alternatively, the same:
"῿:foo".StartsWith(":")           // equals true
"῿:foo".StartsWith("῿")          // equals true
```

Does .NET claim that this string starts with two different characters?

And while I find this *very* surprising and would like to understand the "why", I'm equally interested in how I can force .NET to search exclusively by codepoints instead (using `InvariantCulture` doesn't seem to do a thing)?

And for comparison, one characters below that, `"\u1FFE:foo".StartsWith(":")` returns false.

Comment: from the article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/
`\uxxxx – Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value xxxx`
so it's ignoring everything up to the :foo?

Comment: @Brandon, no, because the length of the string includes that character, I can print the character, serialize it, and `"\u1FFF:".[0]"` returns `\u1FFF`, not `:`. And yes, these are, of course, Unicode escape sequences, but no codepoint in that range is invalid. I updated the q., hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: I notice from [Range: 1F00–1FFF](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F00.pdf) that `U+1FFE` is assigned but `U+1FFF` is not.

Comment: @DourHighArch, if that is true, than that is problematic. Unicode [stipulates](http://www.unicode.org/L2/L1999/99191.htm) that unassigned codepoints should be treated by their block properties. Only very few codepoints should actually be ignored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That a string in general might be considered to start with two different strings that are not byte-for-byte identical is not surprising (because Unicode is complicated).  For example, these results are almost always going to reflect what a user wants:

```
"n\u0303".StartsWith("\u00f1") // true
"n\u0303".StartsWith("n")      // false
```

Using `System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory`, you can see that `'\u1fff'` is in the "OtherNotAssigned" category; it's unclear to me whether that should affect string search/sort/comparison operations (it does not appear to affect normalization, that is, the characters remain after normalization).

If you want a byte-for-byte comparison, use `StringComparison.Ordinal`.

Comment: `StringComparison.Ordinal` is what I needed! For one reason or another, I didn't try it with that one, but _it works!_. I am aware of the Unicode intricacies, and yes, "ñ" and "n" can be considered equal depending on your collation, and normalization may fold `n˜` into `ñ` (but only if the second is U+02DC or U+0303). I thought `InvariantCulture` would not do folding or normalization. Also, no normalization should fold unknown characters, simply because the input can be from a higher Unicode standard, and thus you should leave such characters alone.

Comment: `"n\u0303".StartsWith("n")` being false is also surprising... Good example to show with assigned codepoints.

Comment: @KevinM - those are characters with linguistic meaning, so I certainly expect them affect the results of `StartsWith` (as they do in the `InvariantCulture` setting, or with my local `CurrentCulture`, too).  By contrast, the unassigned characters have no linguistic meaning, so if they are showing up in your strings you should probably be using `Ordinal` comparisons.

Comment: @KevinM - when I run locally, I see the expected results, not sure why the ideone results are all true...

Comment: Hmm, fair enough. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using `String.StartsWith()` incorrectly. You should use `String.StartsWith (String, StringComparison)` overload and `StringComparison.Ordinal`.

There is no character assigned to `\u1FFF`. I.e. there is no linguistic meaning attached to this code. See [Greek Extended, Range: 1F00–1FFF](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F00.pdf) excerpt from character code tables for Unicode Standard. [Best Practices for Using Strings in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings) document from MSDN explicitly states that if you need to compare strings in a manner that ignores features of natural languages then you should use `StringComparison.Ordinal`:

> Specifying the [StringComparison.Ordinal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison.ordinal) or [StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison.ordinalignorecase) value in a method call signifies a non-linguistic comparison in which the features of natural languages are ignored. Methods that are invoked with these [StringComparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison) values base string operation decisions on simple byte comparisons instead of casing or equivalence tables that are parameterized by culture. In most cases, this approach best fits the intended interpretation of strings while making code faster and more reliable.

Moreover, it recommends to always explicitly specify `StringComparison` in such method calls:

> When you develop with .NET, follow these simple recommendations when you use strings:
>
> - Use overloads that explicitly specify the string comparison rules for string operations. Typically, this involves calling a method overload that has a parameter of type [StringComparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=netframework-4.7.1).