# String StartsWith method returns true for byte order mark in any case

Tags: c#, string, utf-8, startswith

I copied blindly one of the stackoverflow answers, but it didn't work for me as I expected.
I needed to remove a UTF8 byte order mark from a string, and somehow, the inputText.StartsWith(byteOrderMark) always returns true for whatever string:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inputText = "hello";
        string byteOrderMark = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
        if (inputText.StartsWith(byteOrderMark))
            inputText = inputText.Remove(0, byteOrderMark.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(inputText); // ello
        Console.WriteLine(inputText[0] == byteOrderMark[0]); // false
    }
}
```

I can check it character by character, there is no problem. I'm interested why StartsWith returns true even when the string doesn't start with UTF8 preamble?

Comment: Probably the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209888/why-does-u1ffffoo-startswith-return-true) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831410/why-does-string-startswith-u2d2d-always-return-true).

Comment: What answer was that?  Probably we should fix it.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama - I added an answer, then saw your [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209888/why-does-u1ffffoo-startswith-return-true).  Should I delete this and close as a duplicate?

Comment: @dbc I kind of like your answer better than the one on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209888/why-does-u1ffffoo-startswith-return-true), though I'm not sure if it's worth you moving it over there.

Comment: @dbc I'm thinking it's possible it's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29176183/3181933) OP saw so I'll fix it.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama - no, that's something different.  That question contains its own implementation for `public static bool StartsWith(this byte[] thisArray, byte[] otherArray)`.

Comment: @dbc Doh! I am an idiot. Thank you for stopping me making too much of a fool of myself. :)

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama - maybe it's [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15616035/3744182)?  Compare with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1319226/3744182) by TrueWill which is actually right, the wrong answer comes first in the "trending" sort.

Comment: @dbc I think you're right, so I've updated it. :)

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama this was definitely one, your googling skills are truly superior.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Also, should I now delete this question?

Comment: @username - it's not a bad duplicate, since the title is very clear.

Comment: @username Duplicates such as this can serve as signposts for other people searching for a solution to the same or similar issues, and I think your question should show up in other people's searches in future, so it isn't a bad idea to leave it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `StringComparison.Ordinal`:

```
if (inputText.StartsWith(byteOrderMark, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    inputText = inputText.Remove(0, byteOrderMark.Length);
```

As explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-7.0#system-string-startswith(system-string)), `String.StartsWith(String)`:

> This method performs a word (case-sensitive and **culture-sensitive**) comparison using the current culture.

Since the BOM is **non-printing**, apparently in your culture your call is equivalent to `inputText.StartsWith(string.Empty)`, which is always true.

The docs further note:

> As explained in [Best Practices for Using Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings), we recommend that you avoid calling string comparison methods that substitute default values and instead call methods that require parameters to be explicitly specified. To determine whether a string begins with a particular substring by using the string comparison rules of the current culture, signal your intention explicitly by calling the [`StartsWith(String, StringComparison)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-7.0#system-string-startswith(system-string-system-stringcomparison)) method overload with a value of [CurrentCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=net-7.0#system-stringcomparison-currentculture) for its comparisonType parameter.

Seems like you may have gotten bitten by this.